# How can I set up Python virtual environment in VScode so that it views locally-installed modules?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have created a virtual environment via the command line

```
python3.11 -m venv .        
source ./bin/activate       
python -m pip install NAME_OF_MODULE
source deactivate
```

I can see the installed modules when I run `pip freeze` (prior to deactiving). So far so good.

Then I launch VSCode, open a file and using the command palette, I click `Python: Select Interpreter`. I then navigate in the bin folder of the virtual environment to the Python installation, which consists of a short-cut / alias pointing to a global Python installation.

When I do this, I cannot import Python modules located in the virtual environment, only those in the global environment. In other words, it appears to be selecting the global environment.

Do I need to set this up within VSCode (`Python: Create Environment`) ? If so, I can only get so far as the official instructions (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) do not cover installing packages within a virtual environment.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to locate and import packages when running the Python REPL from within your virtual environment? Try `cd <venv_path>; source ./bin/activate; python; import <thing>`. If that is not working then you should delete and create your virtual environment. When creating the virtual env, try creating it though VS Code's terminal as opposed to the system terminal. Also, using something like `pipenv` can make working with virtual environments a lot easier.

Comment: I think you didn't choose the venv interpreter. You can refer to [the documents](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this in VSCode, by choosing the Create Environment command from the Command Palette. This created a .venv folder where the Python installation is contained. Then when I go to select the Python interpreter via the Command Palette, it automatically finds the local installation. Then, I installed packages by opening the command line WITHIN VSCode (no need to activate environment - it is already automatically activated).

So the trick is to create the environment WITHIN VSCode, not using the system shell.